# how to undo delete in drupal 6 site

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I have Drupal 6 site.

By mistake, I have deleted view, which is very crucial. 
     http://www.chetan.co.in/admin/build/views/edit/category_grid?destination=category-home#views-tab-page_1

How do I undo this delete operation.

Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

*Take Note: Drupal 6 is no longer officially supported by the community. While there are some places that are offering long term support for Drupal 6, you should plan to move to Drupal 7 or 8 soon.*

You'll most likely need to rebuild the view; Drupal doesn't have a feature to undelete a structure like a view.

That said there are a couple places the view might still exist:

- If you have backups of the database from before the delete, you can load a backup to a new location and export the view from the backup and import it into the production site.

  - If you don't have a backup, stop what you're doing and solve that problem before your situation gets worse.
- If the view is in a feature (module built with the features module),
  you can revert the feature through drush or the features interface.
- If the view came from a module another way you might be able to
  re-install the module (but uninstall may have side effects that are
  worse).

Comment: I am facing one weared issue.

Comment: I have url `node/1`,`node/test`, & I had node-1.tpl.php or node-test.tpl.php initially which was not picked & rendered intially & but suddenly my site is picking these files as templates which is causing some problems. any clue what is causing such sudden strange behaviour.